# Selenium and Python can't click href="javascript:void(0);" with .click()

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have been stuck on trying to click the href="javascript:void(0);" on a page.

My problem is that I am not able to select this using selenium, and my end goal is to click on one. The page is fully loaded, and this is what all the links on the page have as the href.

my code is this:

```
a = soup.find_all('a')
for names in a:
    try:
        print (names['href'])
        if names['href'] == "javascript:void(0);":
            print "IM IN HUR"
            names.click()
            break
    except:
        continue
```

But the "name.click()" statement never works.I have not found any way to click on javascript:void(0). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have to use Selenium WebDriver to interact with web browser. Beautiful Soup is a Python package for parsing HTML/XML, it cannot interact with web browser. Could you show us the code that opens browser and navigates to the website?

Comment: @Buaban I am using selenium as well:

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

Then I do what I did above:

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
a = soup.find_all('a')

for names in a:
    try:
        print names['href']
        if names['href'] == "javascript:void(0);":
            print "IM IN HUR"
            names.click()
            break
    except:
        continue

Comment: names['href'].click() is incorrect. It is a collection of xml nodes so it doesn't have a click() method.

Comment: @Buaban I do reach the if statement at names['href'], is there another way to click on this xml node?

Comment: @Buaban, I'm getting a Nonetype error ONLY on when it hits the if statement. After printing each name.get_attribute("href"), the only time it's type changes from unicode to NoneType is when it reaches this if statement - so essentially when it is "javascript:void". Not sure why this would be happening only in this case. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Are you using the code in my answer?

Comment: @Buaban yeah same thing: 
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'NoneType'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-03ee835012d3> in <module>()
      5 for name in aElements:
      6     print type(name.get_attribute("href"))
----> 7     if("javascript:void" in name.get_attribute("href")):
      8         print("IM IN HUR")
      9         name.click()

TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Comment: I have just updated my answer to check null before check text "javascript:void". Could you try it?

Comment: Could you accept my answer so we can close this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use Selenium WebDriver to interact with web browser. Your variable `names` is an object of Beautiful Soup which is a Python package for parsing HTML/XML, it cannot interact with web browser. Try code below:

```
aElements = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
for name in aElements:
    if(name.get_attribute("href") is not None and "javascript:void" in name.get_attribute("href")):
        print("IM IN HUR")
        name.click()
        break
```